# Instagram like post screen flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to build a picture and camera screen in a page like the Instagram post screen I  tried using storage path which currently only works on android and also returns an error, I want it to work on android and ios so I can easily pick multiple images no cropping or editing needed for the pictures.

[image: image here]

```
class FileModel {
  List<String> files;
  String folder;

  FileModel({this.files, this.folder});

  FileModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    files = json['files'].cast<String>();
    folder = json['folderName'];
  }
}



    import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:storage_path/storage_path.dart';
import 'package:rojar1/models/file_model.dart';

class PostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "/postscreen";
  PostScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _PostScreenState createState() => _PostScreenState();
}

class _PostScreenState extends State<PostScreen> {
  List<FileModel> files;
  FileModel selectedModel;
  String image;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getImagesPath();
  }

  getImagesPath() async {
    var imagePath = await StoragePath.imagesPath;
    var images = jsonDecode(imagePath) as List;
    files = images.map<FileModel>((e) => FileModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    if (files != null && files.length > 0)
      setState(() {
        selectedModel = files[0];
        image = files[0].files[0];
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.clear),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<FileModel>(
                      items: getItems(),
                      onChanged: (FileModel d) {
                        assert(d.files.length > 0);
                        image = d.files[0];
                        setState(() {
                          selectedModel = d;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selectedModel,
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Next',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Divider(),
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                child: image != null
                    ? Image.file(File(image),
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)
                    : Container()),
            Divider(),
            selectedModel == null && selectedModel.files.length < 1
                ? Container()
                : Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.38,
                    child: GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 4,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 4),
                        itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                          var file = selectedModel.files[i];
                          return GestureDetector(
                            child: Image.file(
                              File(file),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                image = file;
                              });
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: selectedModel.files.length),
                  )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem> getItems() {
    return files
            .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                    e.folder,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  value: e,
                ))
            .toList() ??
        [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customized the album at the lower part, then you need to build your own album with this [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager):

get album photos by paged:

```
// page: The page number of the page, starting at 0.
// perPage: The number of pages per page.
final assetList = await path.getAssetListPaged(page, perPage);
```

once you got them, layout whatever you like, like putting images in gridview at the lower part

Comment: Thanks, I've been using that package to get list of media. Do you know how to make it scrollable just like instagram? for now, I can only scroll the grid while the preview is static at the top

Comment: Hey @Jim if you have already made code, can you share it with me via github?